# Delete files in destination folder which no longer exist in source using robocopy

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, robocopy

I have a script which copies files from source to destination recursively using robocopy. It runs once in n mins. I want to delete files from destination which no longer exist in src location. There is an option in robocopy /PURGE but it deletes both files and directories but i want to delete only files. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Run `robocopy` normally and then another time in list-only mode to enumerate the extra files and delete them manually:

```
:loop

rem normal robocopy command without monitoring the source /mon switch
robocopy ..........

rem list the extra files and directories
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('^
    robocopy /njs /njh /ndl /ns /s /l /purge "SOURCEDIR" "TARGETDIR"^
') do (
    if %%a==File del "%%b"
)

timeout 300
goto loop
```